# SQLite under 100K

Tags: sqlite, arm, stm32f4discovery, cortex-m

I need an SQLite version (or similar) that compiles under 100k.
This is to accomodate the application code and drivers along with the SQLite to run on an ARM Cortex M4 based STM32F4 series processor.

No external memory.  Only using the 196k SRAM and 1M Flash.
Considering the 384k SRAM / 2M Flash part but with application code, this is still tight.

No operating system, so I need to write the drivers for Flash.

Currently, I'm trimming down SQLite3.8.  If this has been done by someone, I need to know.

Comment: What features do you actually need?